# My Thunderbolt4 port is not working, how to verify that this is a hardware or OS problem?

Tags: usb, hardware, dock-station, peripherals

I am using Fedora 38 on Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4. Kernel version is 6.3.11. It seems that my Thunderbolt 4 ports are powered on, but whatever I plug to them I get no output. Is there any way to verify that this is due to hardware or lack of support in the operating system?

#### More background

The port used to work, which is why I am suspecting a hardware failure. I used to connect Lenovo dock to it, but one day it just stopped working. Here are some commands I used to check the port is still seen by the OS:

```
boltctl list -a
 ● Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
   ├─ type:          host
   ├─ name:          ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
   ├─ vendor:        Lenovo
   ├─ uuid:          10dae28f-c8a8-8780-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     10dae28f-c8a8-8780-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Sat 08 Jul 2023 22:00:14 UTC
   ├─ connected:     Sat 08 Jul 2023 22:00:14 UTC
   └─ stored:        no

 ● Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
   ├─ type:          host
   ├─ name:          ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
   ├─ vendor:        Lenovo
   ├─ uuid:          21c8aa24-1319-8780-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    USB4
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     21c8aa24-1319-8780-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Sat 08 Jul 2023 22:00:14 UTC
   ├─ connected:     Sat 08 Jul 2023 22:00:14 UTC
   └─ stored:        no
```

The dock is the only T4 device I have and I get a blank output from `boltctl list` if I plug it in. I also tried plugging a standard USB-C pendrive and that doesn’t get detected either.

Running `journalctl -u bolt` gives me:

```
bolt 0.9.5 starting up.
manager: initializing store
store: located at: /var/lib/boltd
config: loading user config
bouncer: initializing polkit
watchdog: enabled [pulse: 90s]
udev: initializing udev
store: loading domains
store: loading devices
power: state located at: /run/boltd/power
power: force power support: no
udev: enumerating devices
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] newly connected [iommu] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0)
security level set to 'none'
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] bootacl: bootacl not supported, no sync
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] udev: failed to determine if uid is stable: unknown NHI PCI id '0x9a1f'
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] udev: uuid is stable: no (for NHI: 0x9a1f)
global 'generation' set to '4'
[10dae28f-c8a8-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] device added, status: authorized, at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0
[10dae28f-c8a8-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] labeling device: Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] newly connected [iommu] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0)
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] bootacl: bootacl not supported, no sync
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] udev: failed to determine if uid is stable: unknown NHI PCI id '0x9a21'
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] udev: uuid is stable: no (for NHI: 0x9a21)
[21c8aa24-1319-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] device added, status: authorized, at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.3/domain1/1-0
[21c8aa24-1319-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] labeling device: Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i
[10dae28f-c8a8-domain0                    ] dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/10dae28f_c8a8_8780_ffff_ffffffffffff
[21c8aa24-1319-domain1                    ] dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/21c8aa24_1319_8780_ffff_ffffffffffff
[10dae28f-c8a8-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] dbus: exported device at /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/10dae28f_c8a8...
[21c8aa24-1319-ThinkPad P1 Gen 4i         ] dbus: exported device at /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/21c8aa24_1319...
Started bolt.service - Thunderbolt system service.
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions of what else can I run to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not know what caused this problem, but doing the following fixed the issue:

1. Power off the computer.
2. Plug it off from the power supply.
3. Use a pin-hole reset button located in the middle on the flip side of the chassis. Hold it for 10s
4. Plug in everything and power up.

Using this pin-hole reset does not affect the file system or anything else. It seems to be a hard reset removing all power supply from all subsystems in models which have built-in battery. The P1 manual states that you use it when standard reset doesn't work.